# Zend Custom Modules Routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, routes

i have this set up:

```
    application
    ---admin
    -----controllers
    -------IndexController.php
    ---public
    -----controllers
    ---modules
    -----users
    -------controllers
    -----pages
    -------controllers
```

I'd like to have this routes :

```
www.domain.com/admin/modulename/controller/action/
```

or if module not exist i use admin controllers

```
www.domain.com/admin/controller/action/
```

Any suggesiton?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bootstrap file write this code :

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
if($moduleName){
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                  ':module/:controller/:action/',
                  array(
                      'controller' => $ControllerName,
                      'module' => '$moduleName',
                      'action'     => $ActionName
                  )
              );
}else{
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                  ':controller/:action/',
                  array(
                      'controller' => $ControllerName,
                      'action'     => $ActionName
                  )
              );
}

$router->addRoute('default', $route);
```